# Java.exe with exited code 1 on Release mode xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I tried to reduce my app size so I choosed sdk assemblies only in linking option in android option in my xamarin app app got compiling error

> Java.exe with exited code 1

how to solve that ?

[image]

Comment: Output and current Android SDK Path

Comment: android sdk path ? you mean api ? i used api 27 for that

Comment: No i mean the path that you have your Android Native SDK's in\

Comment: in c://program files

Comment: In VS go to tools>optiions>Xamarin and then give me path for android SDK location

Comment: C:\SDK\adt\SDK ...

Comment: @AmrKamal solutions for this: 1 - disable Proguard if it is enabled, 2- Set Java Max Heap Size in Android options, 1G for example

Comment: @toumir thank you your tips is helpful  :)